# rsync over a serial connection

Tags: linux, rsync

I need to effectively rsync two directories (running on two different machines) over a serial connection.  I'll have to handle actual file transfer over a custom protocol.

What I'm really after is determining which files to send.  I need to essentially create an index of files (with checksums) on one side, transfer that index to the other side, have it create an index as well on it's side, and then send back a comparison.  And then I'd just only transfer the files that are different.

I can certainly code all of this myself, but I'm hoping Linux has some built in tool to help.  In particular, is there an way to have rsync create some sort of index.  It already does most of the work anyway, but I can't find a way to output that work.

Any ideas on how to do this without custom coding all of it would be great.

Comment: Why not let `rsync` do the file transfer? It would only transfer the chunks of the files that were different. Otherwise, maybe just run `rsync` in dry-run mode and parse the output?

Comment: Can it do that over serial?

Comment: Use `ser2net` and then `rsync` over that as Kusalananda suggests.

Comment: Other alternative is to set up `ppp` connection between machines and then `rsync` over that.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned, running an IP protocol over the serial connection gains a ton of flexibility, and would be the recommended way to go.  But to answer the question originally asked:

> In particular, is there an way to have rsync create some sort of index. It already does most of the work anyway, but I can't find a way to output that work.

If you mean which files should be transferred, no.  `rsync` is comparing files on both sides.  Without knowledge of the destination, that information isn't created.

If you just mean which files are considered (parsing the source files and any includes/excludes), you could generate that list by parsing the `--verbose` output of a `--dry-run` directed to an empty location.

I don't know of a way to calculate/display the block checksums out of a pass.